# firefox addon webrequest.addListener misbehaving

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to examine http requests in an extension for firefox.  To begin figuring out how to do what I want to do I figured I'd just log everything and see what comes up:

```
webRequest.onResponseStarted.addListener(
  (stuff) => {console.log(stuff);},
  {urls: [/^.*$/]}
);
```

The domain is insignificant, and I know the regex works, verified in the console.  When running this code I get no logging.  When I take out the filter parameter I get every request:

```
webRequest.onResponseStarted.addListener(
  (stuff) => {console.log(stuff);}
);
```

Cool, I'm probably doing something wrong, but I can't see what.

Another approach is to manually filter on my own:

```
var webRequest = Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/WebRequest.jsm", {});
var makeRequest = function(type) {
  webRequest[type].addListener(
    (stuff) => {
      console.log(!stuff.url.match(/google.com.*/));
      if(!stuff.url.match(/google.com.*/))
        return;
      console.log(type);
      console.log(stuff);
    }
  );
}
makeRequest("onBeforeRequest");
makeRequest("onBeforeSentHeaders");
makeRequest("onSendHeaders");
makeRequest("onHeadersReceived");
makeRequest("onResponseStarted");
makeRequest("onCompleted");
```

With the console.log above the if, I can see the regex returning true when I want it to and the code making it past the if.  When I remove the console.log above the if the if no longer gets executed.

My question is then, how do I get the filtering parameter to work or if that is indeed broken, how can I get the code past the if to be executed?  Obviously, this is a fire hose, and to begin searching for a solution I will need to reduce the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`urls` must be a string or an array of [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns). Regular expressions are not supported.

`WebRequest.jsm` uses `resource://gre/modules/MatchPattern.jsm`. Someone might get confused with the `util/match-pattern` add-on sdk api, which does support regular expressions.

Comment: From the documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/WebRequest.jsm#onBeforeRequest.  This states that urls is a "Array of RegExp.".  That's pretty clear.  In any case I tried your match patterns from google, no luck.  It almost seems that logging before I do this enables logging inside the request, I just have no idea if it's actually doing what I want it to.